python ffmpeg not decoding text from webcam video frame
I am trying to construct python script with ffmpeg command to capture a webcam, decode the text from the camera frame and stream the same through an RTSP stream. I am able to receive the streaming through the player, but text decoding is not happening with the following example code: Help is needed to understand the problem, whether it is a piping problem or any other mistake in the code.
ffmpeg_cmd = (
    "ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -i hw:0 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/stream"
)

pytesseract_cmd = (
    "pytesseract --tessdata-dir /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/ -l eng --oem 3 --psm 6 stdin stdout"
)

ffmpeg_process = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
pytesseract_process = subprocess.Popen(pytesseract_cmd.split(), stdin=ffmpeg_process.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    frame = np.frombuffer(ffmpeg_process.stdout.read(1280*720*3), dtype=np.uint8).reshape((720, 1280, 3))
    text = pytesseract_process.stdout.readline().strip()
    print(text)


you could add example video because it makes problem. tesseract works better when you have black text on white background. Important can be also size of text - too small text or too big text and tesseract may have problem. See tesseract doc: Improving the quality of the output | tessdoc. So it may need complex code (probably using module opencv) to remove background and keep only text.

you may also test with different psm because sometimes it can help.

btw; did you try to save frame in file e.g. PNG and check it in any image viewer. Maybe you get wrong image from stream. Maybe you should't use .reshape((720, 1280, 3) but rotate or transpose - to rotate image. Or maybe you have to flip image.

you senf ffmpeg to socket as rtsp but you should rather send it to standart outout using -. And it may need raw data instead of rtsp because you read it directly to numpy without converting from some compressed format. See Pipe ffmpeg output to other process - Super User

maybe you should use directly tesseract (C/C++ program) instead of pytesseract (python's wrapper)

this program has many problem - ffmpeg sends data to stream so script can't read it from stdout. It would need to send data to stdout or it would have to create RTSP client which can read stream. ffmpeg sends data in compressed format - so frame can have less bytes than 12807203 and you can't know its size. It may need to send it as raw video. It would need convert data to png before sending to tesseract. And tesseract wait for end of stream before it starts to search text - so it would need to close connection after every image, and create new connection (start new process again).

it may need to create code which runs one thread which reads directly from stream and convert to png. And other thread would have to open tesseract with single image, wait for text (which may take longer time) and get result, and later get next image from first thread, etc.

There are many problems in your code.
ffmpeg creates stream RTSP (and send it by socket) but it doesn't send to stdout so you can't get it with subprocess.PIPE. You have to use - as output (instead of rtsp:///...) or you would have to create RTSP client which reads from rtsp:///...
It sends in format x264 which is compressed - so data can be smaller than 1280*720*3 and it would need to method to decompress it (and it may need to access to previous key frames - and this makes big problem). Besides tesseract needs image PNG. But even using -vcodec png it creates compressed data which may have size smaller than 1280*720*3 and it makes problem to find beginning of next frame - it would need to read in chunks and check magic number for PNG (file PNG should start with 3 bytes P N G) - so it is simpler to get raw data.
It needs PIL to convert data to PNG because tesseract doesn't work with raw data.
Instead of running subprocess with pytesseract you can use directly tesseract or you could import pytesseract and use pytesseract.image_to_text()
Other problem is that tesseract can convert only one image and it waits for end of data in stdin - so it needs to close process after every image, and later create new process for new image.
I'm not sure if tesseract if fast to work with 25 frames per seconds - but I'm not fast enough to read all results with speed25 frames per seconds - so I reduced it to 1 frame per second.

Maybe it would be simpler to create script which uses separate thread to run RTSP Client and keep current frame in shared memory. And other thread should get current frame and run OCR. This way RTSP Client could control if it gets full and correct frame, and other thread wouldn't have to care it it get correct frame but it would have to care of OCR.

This works for me:
import io
import subprocess
from PIL import Image

# my webcam has smaller size
w = 1280//2
h = 720//2

ffmpeg_cmd = (
    "ffmpeg", 
    
    # --- hide all meessage from ffmpeg
    "-hide_banner",
    "-loglevel", "error",

    # --- webcam on Linux ---
    "-f", "v4l2",
    "-framerate", "1",
    "-video_size", f"{w}x{h}",
    "-i", "/dev/video0",

    # --- desktop on Linux ---
    #"-f", "x11grab",
    #"-framerate", "1",
    #"-video_size", f"{w}x{h}",
    #"-i", ":0.0",
    
    # --- create raw data ---
    "-f", "image2pipe", 
    "-vcodec", "rawvideo",  # "-vcodec", "png",  
    "-pix_fmt", "rgb24",
    
    # --- send to stdout ---
    "-"
)

tesseract_cmd = (
    "tesseract",
    "--tessdata-dir", "/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/",
    "-l", "eng", 
    "--oem", "3",
    "--psm", "6",
    "stdin", "stdout"
)

print(" ".join(ffmpeg_cmd))
print(" ".join(tesseract_cmd))


try:

    ffmpeg_process = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    index = 0

    while True:
        index += 1
        
        print(f'frame {index} : read image')
        
        raw_data = ffmpeg_process.stdout.read(w*h*3)

        print(f'frame {index} : write image')
        
        # write on disk - if `"-vcodec", "png"` - but it may writes also trash
        #with open(f'output-{index}.png', 'wb') as f:
        #    f.write(data)

        # create image from raw data
        img = Image.frombuffer("RGB", (w, h), raw_data)
        #img = img.rotate(90)
        #img = img.transpose(method=Image.Transpose.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
        #img.save(f'output-pil-{index}.png')

        # create PNG from image (in memory)
        file_like_object = io.BytesIO()
        img.save(file_like_object, 'PNG')
        data_png = file_like_object.getvalue()

        print(f'frame {index} : tesseract')
        
        tesseract_process = subprocess.Popen(tesseract_cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = tesseract_process.communicate(input=data_png)
        stdout_data = output[0]
        text = stdout_data.decode('utf-8').strip()
        print('text:', text)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\rPressed Ctrl+C, Closing')  # `\r` to remove `^C` from line
finally:    
    ffmpeg_process.kill()    


PIL: Image

Thanks furas, i tried similar to your code and your code as well works, but like you mentioned tesseract is too slow , i am hardly getting  results with 30fps it stuck with intial frames.

OCR works better with black text on white background - but maybe problem is also piping. Maybe you could use OpenCV to read frame from stream - OpenCV OCR and text recognition with Tesseract - PyImageSearch  and How to Use OpenCV With Tesseract in Real-Time for Optical Character Recognition | Encord
